# Daylight saving time in R - Problems with reading in timestamps correctly

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to read 15 minute data from a csv. I have struggles with the daylight saving hours which seem to be detected incorrectly. Here is a small sample of the timestamps I have (my tz = 'Europe/Berlin'). Note that the time shift due to the daylight saving hour is from 03:00 to 02:00 in this example.

```
library(lubridate) 
library(dplyr)

dt <- c('29.10.2017 01:30 - 29.10.2017 01:45',
        '29.10.2017 01:45 - 29.10.2017 02:00',
        '29.10.2017 02:00 - 29.10.2017 02:15',
        '29.10.2017 02:15 - 29.10.2017 02:30',
        '29.10.2017 02:30 - 29.10.2017 02:45',
        '29.10.2017 02:45 - 29.10.2017 03:00',## end of daylight savings
        '29.10.2017 02:00 - 29.10.2017 02:15',
        '29.10.2017 02:15 - 29.10.2017 02:30',
        '29.10.2017 02:30 - 29.10.2017 02:45',
        '29.10.2017 02:45 - 29.10.2017 03:00')
```

My goal is to save the start of each period as POSIXct, but the time shift due to the daylight saving hour is not flagged correctly causing duplicate timestamps.

```
dt <- strsplit(dt, split = ' -') %>% unlist() %>% matrix(byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2) 
dtstart <- as_datetime(dt[, 1], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', tz = "CET") 
dtstart
#  [1] "2017-10-29 01:30:00 CEST" "2017-10-29 01:45:00 CEST"
#  [3] "2017-10-29 02:00:00 CEST" "2017-10-29 02:15:00 CEST"
#  [5] "2017-10-29 02:30:00 CEST" "2017-10-29 02:45:00 CEST"
#  [7] "2017-10-29 02:00:00 CEST" "2017-10-29 02:15:00 CEST"
#  [9] "2017-10-29 02:30:00 CEST" "2017-10-29 02:45:00 CEST"
```

My idea was to use the end of the period and then to subtract 15 minutes, but again duplicates are produced

```
dtend <-  as_datetime(dt[, 2], format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', tz = "CET")
dtend
#  [1] "2017-10-29 01:45:00 CEST" "2017-10-29 02:00:00 CEST"
#  [3] "2017-10-29 02:15:00 CEST" "2017-10-29 02:30:00 CEST"
#  [5] "2017-10-29 02:45:00 CEST" "2017-10-29 03:00:00 CET" ## should be CEST ?
#  [7] "2017-10-29 02:15:00 CET"  "2017-10-29 02:30:00 CET" 
#  [9] "2017-10-29 02:45:00 CET"  "2017-10-29 03:00:00 CET"

dtend[6]-dtend[10]
# Time difference of 0 secs
```

Is there a workaround or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You seem to have duplicates in your dataset itself? Not sure what is the exact issue you're facing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the question to make it clear. The values are not duplicates although they have the same character representation. E.g. the first entry for '29.10.2017 02:45 - 29.10.2017 03:00' is observed in central European summer time and the second  is observed in central European time